# query to get part of a string

Tags: t-sql

```
column1
\\abc\tri\eds\rf1\edr\4ed
\\f.d\tri\ef\poe
\\ghi0j\tri\gf\rf\k\hg\ose
```

'
'
'

i got some rows like that in a column

now i want to get the result set like

```
\\abc\tri\eds
\\f.d\tri\ef\
\\ghij\tri\gf
```

simply from first '\' to end of 4th '\'

Answer (score 1):

In this week's episode of **Horrible Code I Have Written For StackOverflow**...

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(column1, 1,
        CHARINDEX('\', column1,
            CHARINDEX('\', column1,
                CHARINDEX('\', column1, 3) + 1) + 1))
FROM
    TableName
```